# how to pass in class' non-static method into class' data member's constructor

Tags: c++, std-function

I have a class `C` with a method `func`. `C` also has a data member `m_func_taker` whose constructor takes a `std::function` argument. How can I pass in `C::func` into `m_func_taker`'s constructor?

I have some example code (click [here](https://ideone.com/42rVHO) to run):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename out_t, typename in_t>
struct my_type{
    using F = std::function<out_t(in_t)>;
    F m_f;
    my_type(F f) : m_f(f) {}
};

class C{
public:
    my_type<double,double> m_func_taker;
    
    double func(double in) { 
        return 2*in; 
    }
    
    C() : m_func_taker(func) {}
    
    
};


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error: "prog.cpp:19:25: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘double C::func(double)’
C() : m_func_taker(func) {}"

It compiles fine when I change the method to `static` and change

```
C() : m_func_taker(C::func) {}
```

but I can't do that in my real program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the call to the method in a lambda:

```
C() : m_func_taker([this](auto d) { return this->func(d); }) {}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y133br).

---

To construct a `std::function` from a method of a class, you could use `std::bind`:

```
using std::placeholders::_1;
```

```
C() : m_func_taker(std::bind(&C::func, this, _1)) {}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nqdnvd).

---

From c++20, you could simplify this with `std::bind_front`:

```
C() : m_func_taker(std::bind_front(&C::func, this)) {}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TrK6nc).

Comment: C++20 [`std::bind_front()`](//en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind_front) is also in the running.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's much nicer, thanks for the suggestion, added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a lambda (to bind the `this` pointer):

```
class C {
...    
    C() : m_func_taker ([this] (double in) { return this->func (in); }) {}
};
```